# Does HTML/XHTML/XML code differ across localizations?

Tags: .net, html, xml, xhtml, localization

This is a simple (and probably stupid) question, but across different localizations, does HTML, XHTML, or XML code remain the same as if I were typing it up on a system using the "en-us" localization?

E.G., if I have <strong>, <em>, and <font> tags that are generated for an HTML, XHTML or XML document (written on a system using the "en-us" locale, and someone tried to render the document using a system with the "sv-SE" locale, my understanding is that the tags should remain the same. Am I correct in assuming this?

The code is currently generated using the WebBrowser control in the MSHTML namespace of .NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's the same everywhere, as the standard dictates the names of the tags and attributes. It's the stuff in between the tags and the values of the attributes that would be localized.

Comment: Thanks, this is my first time delving into multi-language support for an application, this helps greatly!

Comment: @BasedAsFunk - Good luck with your localization project. Multi-language applications can quickly get much more complex than they started.

Answer (score -2):

If you are coding for HTML5, you can essentially define your own tags too.

```
<div>Hello</div> = <stuff>Hello</stuff>
```

You just need to reference the element in your stylesheet:

```
div { text-align: center; }
stuff {text-align: center; }
```

Comment: No, this is false. You still have to stick to the elements defined in the standard. That it happens to work in most browsers is no reason to think its allowed by the standard or something you should do.